# Update user data after login in Symfony 3

Tags: php, authentication, symfony

I am getting in touch with Symfony, this is my first app and I am trying to understand all the environment. This is a very simple question but after a long surf by the web I didn't get how to do it.

I have a login form working very nice with a listener to handle success or error, all works nice but the problem comes when I try to update the last access date for the user.

I have an user entity (taken from the docs):

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastLogin = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function setSalt($salt)
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    public function isAccountNonExpired()
     {
         return true;
     }

     public function isAccountNonLocked()
     {
         return true;
     }

     public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
     {
         return true;
     }

     public function isEnabled()
     {
         return $this->isActive;
     }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->createdAt,
            $this->lastLogin,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->isActive,
            $this->createdAt,
            $this->lastLogin,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Updates last user login date
     *
     */
    public function updateLastLogin()
    {
        $this->lastAccess = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    public function getLastLogin()
    {
        return $this->lastLogin->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
}
```

When the user logs in I call the `updateLastLogin` method:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class LoginListener {

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function onSuccessfulLogin(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if($user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface){
            $user->updateLastLogin();
        }
    }

    public function onLoginError(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        // Login error
    }
}
```

The `updateLastLogin` code is reached but it doesn't get updated in the database. Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

---

The @mdma answer lead me to the right solution, with his solution I got a `Call to a member function getManager() on string` error. To solve it I just injected the `EntityManager` in the listener constructor and added the missing  call to persist the data in the database:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class LoginListener {

    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager){
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onSuccessfulLogin(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if($user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface){
            $user->updateLastLogin();
            $this->entityManager->persist($user);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
    }

    public function onLoginError(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        // Login error
    }
}
```

And in the `services.yml` file I added it as argument:

```
app.login_service:
    class:        AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments:    ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.authentication.success, method: onSuccessfulLogin }
```

Now it works as expected.

Notice there is a typo in the user class when updating the login date, I was using a variable which doesn't exist. Instead of `$this->lastAccess = new \DateTime("now");` it must be:

```
$this->lastLogin = new \DateTime("now");
```

Comment: Great question and great explanation! Why would someone vote this negatively??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are updating the entity class(object). To save it in the database you should use the doctrine manager service.

in a controller you do something like this:  [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// tells Doctrine you want to (eventually) save the Product (no queries yet)
$em->persist($product);

// actually executes the queries (i.e. the INSERT query)
$em->flush();
```

but you are not in a controller so you can inject the doctrine service in the constructor and persist your entity on the event.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class LoginListener {
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct($doctrine){
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function onSuccessfulLogin(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        if($user instanceof AdvancedUserInterface){
            $user->updateLastLogin();
            $this->doctrine->getManager()->persist($user);
            $this->doctrine->getManager()->flush();
        }
    }

    public function onLoginError(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        // Login error
    }
}
```

and in your service definition:

```
services:
    app.login_service:
        class:        AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
        arguments:    [doctrine]
```

Comment: Thank you @mdma but I tried this and it gives me a "Call to a member function getManager() on string" error now

Comment: try harder, you got a perfect answer here!

Comment: Alberto, just like @LBA, I believe this is the perfect answer. Make sure you typed in your code exactly as shown in this answer. It sounds like you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: @AlvinBunk I was checking for typos before posting the comment, but I will try it again later when I have a leisure.

Comment: I have checked again and there are no typos, I finally solved it by injecting the `EntityManager` instead of `doctrine`. To do this, in the constructor pass `EntityManager $entityManager` and remove the `getManager()` parts. Then, in the services.yml file change `[doctrine]` for `["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]`. I am going to upvote this answer because it lead me to the solution, edit it and I accept it. Thank you